# Deploying flask app to Cloud Run with Pytorch

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a Flask app to cloud run using the cloud shell editor. I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to build the app. Error: unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install torch==1.8.0' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is the docker file I am using:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip3 install torch==1.8.0
RUN pip3 install sentence-transformers==2.0.0
RUN pip3 install ultimate-sitemap-parser==0.5
RUN pip3 install Flask-Cors==3.0.10
RUN pip3 install firebase-admin
RUN pip3 install waitress==2.0.0
RUN pip3 install Flask gunicorn

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

This is my first time deploying to cloud run and I am very inexperienced using Docker. Can you give me any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: How do you build your container? Locally? With CLoud Build? Do you have other error logs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I used Cloud Build. However, I have changed the first line to FROM python:3.8 and it is now working.

Comment: Great, a simple python version issue :) You can post your answer to help the others

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
```

To

```
FROM python:3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your torch installation. Check all the requirements for torch is mentioned in your docker file.Or go with a stable version of torch.